# How to add a special-case row in a empty Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, null

I would like to create a DataFrame that has only a row with default values based on the type (StringType, IntegerType, etc.) of the columns. Something like this:

```
// +----+----+
// |col1|col2|
// +----+----+
// |  -1| n/a|
// +----+----+
```

How can I do it?

Alternatively I think it would be enough to have a row of only null values and then i could apply the following function I wrote:

```
def addNaRow(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    val emptyDf = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], df.schema)
    val rowDf = df.schema.foldLeft(df)
    { (accDf, col) =>
      col.dataType match {
        case IntegerType =>
          accDf.withColumn(col.name, lit(-1))
        case StringType =>
          accDf.withColumn(col.name, lit("n/a"))
          // TODO add cases with other types
      }
    }
    rowDf.union(df)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def addNaRow(df: DataFrame, spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
    val df1 = spark.range(1).select(df.schema.map(s => s.dataType match {
       case IntegerType => lit(-1).alias(s.name)
       case StringType => lit("n/a").alias(s.name)
    }):_*)

    df.union(df1)
}
```